# Handle HTTP request failing

Tags: javascript, http, typescript, angular

I have an `http` request to a server:

```
this.http.post('http://192.168.1.45:3000/testrestapi', 'user=username', {
    headers: headers
  })
  .retry(1)
  .timeout(5000)
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log('response is ready');
  }), (err) => {
    console.log('error + ', err);
  }, () => {
    console.log('Done http request');
  };
```

I would like the request to be retried 1 time if it fails. I would also like the request to timeout after 5 seconds. I need to know if the retries and timeouts have all failed so I can handle it.

With the code above I can't seem to be able to handle it. For example if the request has gone through 2 retries I need to know it has so I can handle appropriately. I thought it would appear in the 'error' section, but the console log is never printed at all.

Answer (score 1):

**First**: You are lost in brackets... the `subscribe` application has to be closed after the callbacks:

```
this.http.post('http://192.168.1.45:3000/testrestapi', 'user=username', {headers: headers})
  .timeout(3000, new Error('timeout exceeded'))
  .map(res => res.json())
  .retry(1)
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log('response is ready');
  }, (err) => {
    console.log('error + ', err);
  }, () => {
    console.log('Done http request');
  });
```

to prevent such errors, [TSLint](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/) could help. In this case i got:

> TSLint: expected an assignment or function call (no-unused-expression)

**Second**:
the `retry` call has to be after the `map` call.

Comment: Thanks, but it is still not working.Non of the console.log statements are being printed. The server it is sending the request to has been turned off so I am expecting after 10 seconds (2 request including the 1 retry and 5 seconds per request) and error to occur. I just need to capture this error so I can handle it.

Comment: to throw an error on timeout: `.timeout(5000, new Error('timeout exceeded'))`
but the retry is still not working

Comment: I have tried this now, but still nothing is showing up in my console. No errors.

Comment: take a look at your network tab... do you see the requests there?

Comment: no, no requests are being made. If I remove retry and timeout then the requests start. Seems like a problem with retry and timeout?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107265/discussion-between-meiko-and-user2924127).

Comment: Found the issue: I had to import from: import 'rxjs/add/operator/retry';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/timeout'; Now the requests get sent, although the retry happens right after the first requests instead of waiting for the first one to fail.

Comment: sorry, i cannot reproduce that behaviour. You say requestS ? so you are trying this with multiple requests in parallel... ?

Comment: No. With this code when the page loads it makes the initial request and retry request at the same time. So if if I have retry(1), immediately when the page loads I will have 2 messages saying "POST http://192.168.1.45:3000/testrestapi net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" in the console. If I put retry(10) then I will have that error message display 11 times as soon as the page loads.

Comment: ah ok :) try a different ip, something different from your server... maybe 192.168.11.44:77

Comment: I changed retry to retryWhen and put a delay of 1 second so now the retries wait 1 second  .retryWhen(error => error.delay(1000)) . Still have a problem though. If I turn off my server and send the http request it will retrythe request, this works fine. But now I have turned on my server, but made it so the server wont response with the data for 20 seconds. So if I have a timeout of 5 seconds here the request should timeout. It does timeout, but it does not retry again.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following to handle retry:

```
this.http.post('http://192.168.1.45:3000/testrestapi', 'user=username', {
  headers: headers
})
    .retryWhen(error => error.delay(500))
    .timeout(2000, () => return new Error('delay exceeded'))
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log('response is ready');
    }, (err) => {
      console.log('error + ', err);
    }, () => {
      console.log('Done http request');
    });
```

Without the `retryWhen`, the retry is executed right now...

See this link for more details:

- https://jaxenter.com/reactive-programming-http-and-angular-2-124560.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have copied this code, but I am getting many errors with this code:  On the line where timeout is I get : Argument expression expected and ';' expected. The line where the map is I get the error: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Promise<{}>'. I am importing map from  import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; .